# How to extract textContent from a list of classes in Puppeteer

Tags: css-selectors, puppeteer

In Puppeteer how can I extract the date and list of items purchased on that date? I can extract each class separately with a `querySelectorAll([class='date or item'])` but don't know how to do it all at one time.

I wish to extract Jan 1, 2022, item-1, item-2, item-3, Feb 1, 2022, item-4, Mar 1, 2022, item-5, item-6.

```
 <ul>
   <li>
       <div class=”date”>Jan 1, 2022</div>
           <div class=”item”>item-1</div>
           <div class=”item”>item-2</div>
           <div class=”item”>item-3</div>
    </li>
   <li>
       <div class=”date”>Feb 1, 2022</div>
           <div class=”item”>item-4</div>
    </li>   
    <li>
       <div class=”date”>Mar 1, 2022</div>
           <div class=”item”>item-5</div>
           <div class=”item”>item-6</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure if you want a flat array or an array organized by date (the second option seems much clearer to me), but here's both:

```js
// flat array of both classes
console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".date, .item")]
    .map(e => e.textContent)
);

// date array of objects
console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".date")].map(e => ({
    date: e.textContent,
         // or e.parentNode
    items: [...e.closest("li").querySelectorAll(".item")]
      .map(e => e.textContent)
  }))
);

// object keyed by dates, if they're unique
console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".date")].reduce((a, e) => {
    a[e.textContent] =
      [...e.closest("li").querySelectorAll(".item")]
        .map(e => e.textContent)
    ;
    return a;
  }, {})
);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="date">Jan 1, 2022</div>
    <div class="item">item-1</div>
    <div class="item">item-2</div>
    <div class="item">item-3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="date">Feb 1, 2022</div>
    <div class="item">item-4</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="date">Mar 1, 2022</div>
    <div class="item">item-5</div>
    <div class="item">item-6</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Here's how to scrape the alternate HTML structure with nested image tags based on your new requirements from the comments and [this follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71742581/how-can-i-extract-class-data-and-other-tag-attributes-at-one-time):

```js
console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".date, .item")]
    .flatMap(e =>
      e.classList.contains("item")
      ? [...e.querySelectorAll("img")]
          .map(e => e.getAttribute("alt"))
      : e.textContent
    )
);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="date">Mar 1, 2022</div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://image.com/img3.jpg" alt="item-3">
      <img src="http://image.com/img5.jpg" alt="item-5">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="date">Mar 3, 2022</div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://image.com/img2.jpg" alt="item-2">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please explain the context of "..." in document and e.closest

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: How would the code have change if items-1 through items-5 were actually values in a tag which followed the items class? So instead of <div class="item"> it was actually of the form <div class="item"><src="web address><alt="item-1">. In this case it is the textContent you want for the date but the value of the tag for the item.

Comment: `<src="web address><alt="item-1">` isn't really valid HTML -- these are usually attributes on an image like `<img src="foo" alt="bar">`, so I can't tell what you're working with here. I suggest posting a new question if this is a different structure you want scraped. If these are details omitted from the original question, please edit your original question to provide a link to the page you're scraping or provide a minimal, accurate representation of the HTML with the exact output you expect to eliminate back-and-forth and moving goalpost requirements. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, yes <img src="some web address"><alt="item-1">. The point was that in the flat array solution offered, textContent was able to be used for both the date and the item. But if the item is actually the value of a tag, textContent is needed for the 'date' but the value of the attribute needs to be used for the 'item'.

Comment: <img src="some web address" alt="item-1"> would be the correct HTML context

Comment: OK, so `e.getAttribute("alt")` is what you want?

Comment: Yes I was trying to integrate the e.getAttribute('alt') into the sample code provided. Per your suggestion I did post this as a stand alone question,.

Comment: Ok, I see based on your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71742581/6243352) (which is such a small tweak it'd have been fine to edit this post to clarify), the image is inside of the div rather than in its place. Try `.map(e => e.querySelector("img").getAttribute("alt"))` instead of `.map(e => e.textContent)`

Comment: How can that be integrated in the flat array version that you posted?

Comment: I made an edit showing how, but IMO the flat structure is the least useful of the three, so it seems likely you'll run into trouble with it in the future (for example, how would you query which items belong to which date easily?). I assume your use case is aware of this.